# Dyalog (APL) +RIDE issue

Tags: networking, arch-linux, software-installation, macos

I am currently running a vanilla Arch machine and I wanted to try out APL. Dyalog only provides deb and rpm packages, but I saw a dyalog-bin pkgbuild in the AUR, and it seems to be pulling from the deb repo.

The problem I am facing is that for whatever reason RIDE just cannot seem to connect to Dyalog or even start it up. I have opened up ports made sure that localhost is resolvable.

I even updated the version of dotnet runtime to be used to 6.0 as one of the solutions in the Dyalog forums.

I am able to run it in tty mode and it works interactively. But somehow Ride always gets timed out.

I also tried using their official docker image, but I ran into the same problem there. I tried installing ride on a spare Mac that I had and tried to setup a connection to my Linux box, but I found the same issue with the Mac. The container version worked in the HTTP mode, and I was able to connect to the interpreter using a browser but I couldn't connect it with ride.

I don't have a windows machine currently, so I could not test there.

If anyone has used dyalog, please let me know if there's some setting that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RIDE or APL generally, but I gather RIDE is an IDE. I doubt you're going to find a specific answer to "gets timed out" without more error data or networking details from within your install. Even then... there are just so many configuration issues that come up with IDEs generally that it's hard to say whether this has any system related causes. You might have better luck on SO, considering this is about setting up a development environment. Otherwise, your best bet is to ask on their APL Orchard chat. If you do find a solution there, consider resharing here as an answer.

Comment: @BryKKan I wanted to ask APL Orchard as that would be the best place but I never had a stackexchange account, and its only after I made one I realized that I need 20 reputations. The other channels that I've tried including their github didn't net me any results probably because the community is small as is.

Comment: @homeCorn There are several ways you can increase your rep to get over that hurdle. The easiest is to browse through other questions and look for any you might be able to answer well yourself. You can also offer edits to posts you see with obvious minor issues like misspelled words or broken links. [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on Meta has more details. 20 rep shouldn't take too long, but I went ahead and posted a chat message on your behalf. I'm not active there, so no idea if that will help, but maybe you'll get lucky.